# g++ compiling CLang standalone app but CMake isn't

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I am trying to compile my `CLang` standalone app using `cmake` on my Ubuntu machine, but no luck yet. Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Demo)

execute_process(
    COMMAND llvm-config --cxxflags
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_CXX_FLAGS
)

execute_process(
    COMMAND llvm-config --ldflags
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_LD_FLAGS
)

execute_process(
    COMMAND llvm-config --libs
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LLVM_LIB_FLAGS
)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${LLVM_CXX_FLAGS}")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} ${LLVM_LD_FLAGS}")

add_executable(clangTestApp TestCLang.cpp)

target_link_libraries(clangTestApp ${LLVM_LIB_FLAGS})
```

Here is the output when I am running `cmake ..` from build directory inside project directory:-

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (add_executable):
  Target "clangTestApp" links to item "-lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMInstrumentation
  -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMArchive -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMDebugInfo -lLLVMJIT
  -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMTableGen
  -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo
  -lLLVMHexagonAsmPrinter -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo
  -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -lLLVMMBlazeAsmParser -lLLVMMBlazeDisassembler
  -lLLVMMBlazeCodeGen -lLLVMMBlazeDesc -lLLVMMBlazeInfo
  -lLLVMMBlazeAsmPrinter -lLLVMCppBackendCodeGen -lLLVMCppBackendInfo
  -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info
  -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo
  -lLLVMCellSPUCodeGen -lLLVMCellSPUDesc -lLLVMCellSPUInfo
  -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc
  -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMARMDisassembler
  -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo
  -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCDesc
  -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMSparcCodeGen
  -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser
  -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter
  -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMR600CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter
  -lLLVMR600Desc -lLLVMR600Info -lLLVMR600AsmPrinter -lLLVMMCDisassembler
  -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts
  -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMMCJIT
  -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject
  -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport

  " which has leading or trailing whitespace.  This is now an error according
  to policy CMP0004.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/prakhar/Desktop/CLang/Demo/build
```

Now when I am running make inside build directory, its giving me:-

```
Scanning dependencies of target clangTestApp
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/clangTestApp.dir/TestCLang.o
Linking CXX executable clangTestApp
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [clangTestApp] Error 4
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/clangTestApp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't know why c++ is saying `no input files`. If anybody have a clue whats going on?

Thanks

Comment: The compilation fails because the creation of proper makefiles fails. And creation of proper makefiles fails because `cmake` fails. And `cmake` fails because trailing whitespace in the library list (notice those those newlines between the last library and the closing quote?).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for fast reply. Can you tell me how to remove that newline? Or maybe I am using some obsolete way of setting link libraries.

Comment: Check the [documentation for `execute_process`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:execute_process). I'm sure there's some option for it that might help. ;)

Comment: OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE is the option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a FindClang.cmake which you can find e.g. here: https://github.com/woboq/woboq_codebrowser/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindClang.cmake (Or just google for FindClang.cmake). You'll also need the corresponding FindLLVM.cmake (https://github.com/woboq/woboq_codebrowser/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindLLVM.cmake)

Comment: I could, but its not like these extra files will make it platform independent as we are searching for `llvm-config` executable inside `/opt/local/bin`, hence will work on linux only (or may be on Mac OS X as well). So, why not keep it simple? I don't see any other benefits.

Comment: Sure, but you can see from these files also how to use the output from llvm-config, no?